# OpenSSL fingerprint embedding on Mac OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, openssl, dynamic-library

I have built a dynamic library on Mac OS X, a .dylib file, that compiles just fine. 
In order to run an application using the .dylib some functions in a file named fips_premain.c run before 'main' to check if a fingerprint was embedded in the .dylib properly. All one has to do in the case of a static library is run an executable named incore_macho on the static library and the fingerprint will check out. In the case of the dynamic library I get a failure when I get xcode to run incore_macho on the dylib with the following output:

```
/User/.../Debug/libcompute-osx.dylib is not a mach-o executable file (filetype 6 should be 2)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

incore-macho will only run on type 2 files (i.e. MH_EXECUTE from , in other words, executables). Type 6 is the MH_DYLIB (the dynamic library you are checking). That's what the error message is saying. According to it, it's just not suited for dylibs.

Answer (score 0):

> All one has to do in the case of a static library is run an executable named incore_macho on the static library and the fingerprint will check out.

This is not exactly correct. You cannot embed the FIPS fingerprint into a static library because code and data will be relocated during the final link to an executable. You *can* embed a fingerprint in a executable program or shared object since they have had their final linking performed.

---

> In the case of the dynamic library I get a failure when I get xcode to run incore_macho on the dylib with the following output

The OpenSSL Foundation has a fix for this. Here's the change needed to allow incore'ing of a dylib. Modify `incore_macho.c` as follows:

Around line 530:

```
else if( !(header->filetype == MH_EXECUTE || header->filetype == MH_DYLIB) )
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s is not a mach-o executable file "
        "(filetype %d, should be MH_EXECUTE or MH_DYLIB)\n",
        inFile->filename, header->filetype);
    return -1;
}
```

Around line 690:

```
else if( !(header->filetype == MH_EXECUTE || header->filetype == MH_DYLIB) )
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s is not a mach-o executable file "
        "(filetype %d should be MH_EXECUTE or MH_DYLIB)\n",
        inFile->filename, header->filetype );
}
```

And that's it... Anywhere you find a test for `MH_EXECUTE`, also allow `MH_DYLIB`.

Or, download the updated `incore_macho.c` from [Github](https://github.com/noloader/incore_macho). They updated `incore_macho.c` also includes support for ARMv7s.